# Largest asymptotic growth for $2f(x)-f(2x)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, asymptotics, functional-equations, growth-rate

I am trying to find smooth functions $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that the quantity $$\Delta_f(x) := 2f(x)-f(2x)$$
is positive for $x$ large enough and has the **greatest asymptotic growth**.

---

It seems clear that one cannot go beyond a linear growth, since $\Delta_f$ vanishes for linear functions and will likely be negative for super-linear ones. However, one can construct many examples of almost linear asymptotic growths.

For example, plugging $f(x) := x^a$ for some $a\in(0,1)$ yields $\Delta_f(x) = (2-2^a) x^a$.

Choosing $f(x) := \frac{x}{\ln x}$ yields $\Delta_f(x) \sim 2 \ln 2 \frac{x}{(\ln x)^2}$ which has a larger asymptotic growth.

---

What would be your candidates for even larger asymptotic growths? And is there a way to prove a (sublinear) a priori upper bound on $\Delta_f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us discretise the problem by setting $a_n=2^{-n}f(2^n)$, $b_n=2^{-n-1}\Delta_f(2^n)$. Then your relation becomes,
$$b_n=a_n-a_{n+1}.$$
since $a_n,b_n$ are non-negative, we conclude that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n<\infty.$$
This is a necessary and sufficient condition. Indeed, take any summable sequence $b_n$ of positive numbers, then we can define
$$a_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k$$ as the sequence of partial sums, and obtain your equation on the sequence $x_n=2^n$. Then you can interpolate by choosing $f(x)$ arbitrarily on the interval $(1,2)$.

Returning to your original notation, the growth condition becomes
$$\int\frac{\Delta_f(x)}{x^2}dx<\infty.$$
This is a necessary and sufficient condition.
For example, we cannot have $\Delta_f(x)\sim x/\log x$, but can have
$$\Delta_f(x)\sim\frac{x}{\log x(\log\log x)^{1+\epsilon}},$$
and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this nice viewpoint on the question. With this approach, I understand that finding the largest asymptotic growth for $\Delta_f$ is reduced to finding the largest asymptotic behavior for a summable sequence $b_n$. When $b_n$ is decreasing, I think it is known that $b_n = o(1/n)$, so your approach would suggest that one cannot obtain better than $\Delta_f(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$?

Comment: There is no "largest" growth of $\Delta_f$ like there is no "slowest" decrease of a sequence which ensures that a series is convergent. For every function $g(x)=\Delta_f(x)$ satisfying your condition there is a sequence of larger growth also satisfying this condition.

Comment: Of course, the wording "the largest" is inappropriate. Thanks for editing your answer with the continuous version of the condition. I guess it now provides an answer to the sublinear bound I was looking for.